# How to create dbf file with dBase IV structure via Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0?

Tags: c#, oledb, dbf, oledbconnection

I use for decision of the task parameter **Extended Properties** for creating of OleDbConnection:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\;Extended Properties=dBase IV;");
con.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "create table test ([id] int,[name] varchar(100))";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//... some code
con.Close();
```

but I get dbf file with dBase III structure. How to fix it?

Comment: For questions like this always go to www.connectionstrings.com.  See : https://www.connectionstrings.com/dbf-foxpro/

Comment: I think that it's bad idea. There are few dbf questions on that forum.

Comment: DBF has not variable length fields. In general modern compatibility layers (.NET and others) for DBF can't exactly build specific dialect, try to be universal. These are (IMHO) for reading and migration